# Adding a fragment to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have an app with functionality to show one record or a list of them. I have a fragment for single record, so I decided for a list I want to fill a RecyclerView with cards, and add a fragment into each card. I am getting IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add a null child to a ViewGroup on a line in onBindViewHolder():

```
holder.frameLayout.addView(ResultFragment.newInstance(id).getView())
```

Comment: Fragment is not yet initialized to call `getView` , this is available after `onViewCreated` is called and whole life cycle of fragment is started after you add your fragment to `FragmentManager`, fragments arent designed for recyclerviews.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure how to work with a Recycled View and Fragments but if you use a  linearLayout or RelativeLayout, you can use FragmentManager in the onCreateView method or generate you're pwn method to change the content in the view (fragment) that you want to change:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
  transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
  oneFragment = new OneFragment();
  transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContent, oneFragment);
  transaction.commit();
```

the R.id.fragmentManager are a `<fragment>` section in your view

Regards